# Where are my lutris games saved?

Tags: wine, games

Where do I need to look for the directory where games installed with lutris are saved? I didn't find anything in ~/.local/share/lutris or in ~/.wine.

Comment: Have you tried `find ~ -type f -mtime -1 -ls` to list files created less than one day ago?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using Lutris with. If you're using Retroarch, that would be the folder:

`/home/user/.config/retroarch/saves`